# References the Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i'm making a project in visual studio and there are references in my project such as **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** .. etc

I set CopyLocal of **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** to *False*

and the directory of **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** is  *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll*

after i build my application then i install it on another computer,

you know, in another computer there are no files like Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll or the like in ***"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\"*** to be used for my application.
but strangely, my application is work fine.

**Why Did This Happen?**

Comment: Maybe it exist in Global Assembly Cache ?

Comment: Reno. Can you tell me more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primary Office Assemblies which includes Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel are installed with Office, therefore you can use it without Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh3965hw(v=vs.100).aspx